# Data to be passed along with an event under Messaging pattern architectire

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

Is it a good idea to pass a model or a collection data in a message on every event. E.g.

```
messageBus.on('someEvent',modelData);
```

and the subscriber than receives the data.

Or it is better to have kind of service (JS module) which would store and update the data on a model/collection throughout the app lifecycle and there should be an event `'data:changed'` raised on every occasion, when `this.data`a is updated.

The subscriber would then look up the changes in a service `this.data` on every `'data:changed'`

The first approach seems to be convenient since there is no need to create a service in addition to a model (BackboneJS) when I do not really need a service. But is there any disadvantages in sending data on every event? E.g. memory consumptions, etc.

Comment: the first approach is, IMHO, the better one. It's much clearer to write and I don't think performance is an issue here since you'll probably be passing the data by reference, thus the size of the data prop on your event doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue here is coupling. Try to avoid dependencies where you can.

The second approach tightly couples your code with `this.data` variable. This is bad style and makes it harder to test the code.

The first approach is better because the data is received as a parameter. This means you can write simple unit tests for your data changed handlers to verify the behavior.

For further advice, I recommend to study the Flux design pattern used in Facebook React https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html. It describes simple one-way message-based data flow.